# Saving Data without nested data

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I am facing a problem, when I try to save a model with nested attributes in it.  I have to models. A Person has many Shirts. But when I try to save a Person via JSON POST Request. Only the Person gets stored, but not the shirts. Does anyone have an idea, what I am missing here?

Model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shirts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :shirts

    validates :shirts, presence: true
end
```

Controller

```
class PersonsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
     @person = Person.new
  end

  def create
        @person = Person.new(person_params)
  ...
  def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age, :shirts_attributes => [:color, :size])
  end
end
```

POST localhost:3000/persons

```
{
    "name" : "Jon",
    "age" : 34,
    "shirts_attributes" : [
      {
        "color" : "black",
        "size" : "XL"
      },
      {
        "color" : "white",
        "size" : "XS"
      }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Please post your `new` method and `form code`.

Comment: Why is the form code needed? I am doing a POST request to the URL http://localhost:3000/persons including the JSON posted?

Comment: Do you posted the wrong controller code? What is `CalendersController` doing here?

Comment: You should post the `PersonsController`.

Comment: @Pavan, you are right, I edited the code...

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`build`** to save the `shirts` as well with `person`.Your `new` method of the `PersonsController` should be like this

```
def new
 @person = Person.new
 @person.shirts.build #This is what you needed.
end
```

Comment: I think this is not how nested_attributes is supposed to work. rails magic should automatically wrap the nested json to models ?!

Comment: I tried it, but it still won't save the shirts.. I found out, that if I add   wrap_parameters include: [:shirts_attributes] to the PersonsController it does, but I am not sure why? Anyway, thanks a lot for your help and support @Pavan